# permission to read data from internal storage Android

Tags: android

I'm new at Mobile developing. I'm trying to create an app with the crossfade effect. But I need to read files from without button clicking after opening. Can you help in solution this question. This is my code. And please tell me "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" after adding that, can I read all files in the phone? It's important to know, because I want to find mp3 files in the my phone and set them instead of buttons

```
package com.example.crossfade

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.crossfade.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.buttonOneTrack.setOnClickListener {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onStoragePermissionGranted()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                RQ_PERMISSION_FOR_BUTTON_1
            )
        }
    }
    binding.buttonTwoTrack.setOnClickListener {

    }
}
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            RQ_PERMISSION_FOR_BUTTON_1 -> {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    onStoragePermissionGranted()
                } else {
                    if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                         askUserForOpeningSettings()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Спасибо, мы можем продолжать", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

private fun askUserForOpeningSettings() {
    val appSettingsIntent = Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
    )
    if (packageManager.resolveActivity(appSettingsIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ура! Ну наконец-то!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Нужно разрешение")
            .setMessage("Надо зайти в настройки и включить. Подробно лень писать")
            .setPositiveButton("Open") {_, _ ->
                startActivity(appSettingsIntent)
            }
            .create()
            .show()
    }
}

private companion object {
    const val RQ_PERMISSION_FOR_BUTTON_1 = 1
    const val RQ_PERMISSION_FOR_BUTTON_2 = 2
    }
private fun onStoragePermissionGranted() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Спасибо, мы можем продолжать!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: You have not published the code that finds files but not all.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You'll never be able to read all the files on your phone-  each app has their own private storage where nobody else can read their files unless they allow it.  Ignoring that-  no.  Not as of Android 11.  See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage and https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files